# Compare the content of two different files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example, `file1.txt, contains only variables:

```
a
b
d
c
```

`file2.txt` contains `<`, variable and path:

```
< a /x/y/1.c
< c /x/d/7.h
< f /x/c/6.s
< b /x/v/8.mk
< t /x/1.h
< d /x/5.so
```

`file1.txt` variables should be compared with `file2.txt`. If a match is found, the complete variable and path should be printed from `file2.txt`.

Expected output:

```
< a /x/y/1.c
< b /x/v/8.mk
< d /x/5.so
< c /x/d/7.h
```

I tried with `comm -3 file1.txt file2.txt`, but it is not effectively working.

`diff` can't be used in my case.

Comment: Hi can we compare the variables as below

text1.txt file :
a

c

d

text2.txt file :
a

b

c

d

e

I am trying to compare file1.txt contents with file2.txt contents I used comm,diff, join commands  they are not giving the desired results

Expected Output is like :

b

e

file1.txt compares with file2.txt and if a match is found it shouldnt  print the matched contents.It means i want only the variables which differs in both file1.txt and file2.txt

Answer (score 0):

if the lines in file2.txt not start with <,  you can use this;

```
join <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

if starts with < char, you can use this;

```
join -11 -22 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

Eg;

```
user@host:/tmp$ join -11 -22 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
a < /x/y/1.c
b < /x/v/8.mk
c < /x/d/7.h
d < /x/5.so
```

-11 means file1.txt and first column, 
 -22 means file2.txt and second column (after "<" char)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for when the keys are not anywhere in the path:
Try this

```
cat file2.txt | grep -f file1.txt
```

Switch the file names as need.

Comment: It can return more than expected if path contains keys

Comment: That is true, I did not take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for shell but I would answer via python

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
    d = dict((e.rstrip().split()[1], e) for e in f)

with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as f:
    for e in f:
        e = e.rstrip()
        if e in d:
            print(d[e], end="")
```

If you saved it to `run.py`, you can call it such that

```
python3 run.py file2.txt file1.txt > output.txt
```

It also preserves the order of `file1.txt` compared to sorting solutions but loads second file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

AWK is good for these things:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR {keys[$0] = 1; next}keys[$2]' file1.txt file2.txt
< a /x/y/1.c
< c /x/d/7.h
< b /x/v/8.mk
< d /x/5.so
```

Basically file1.txt is buffered in the `keys` array. And then each line from file2 is printed if column 2 is in said array:

Comment: @BabaD I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: In one of my case i am trying to print the variables which differs in both file1.txt, file2.txt.
I tried using comm, diff, Join but iam not getting effective results for large number of files..

Comment: `In one of my case i am trying to print the variables which differs in both file1.txt, file2.txt.` Just change `keys[$2]` to `!keys[$2]`